# uploading image to json server sending null NSUrlRequest

Tags: iphone, json

I am trying to upload the image to json server but url request is going null. Below is the code i am using.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

UIImage *imageToScale=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImage *img = imageToScale;
//NSLog(@"finalImage---------------------------------%@",self.finalImage);
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.40);

profileImg = profilePic;

NSArray *arrImg = [profileImg componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *strImg1 = [arrImg objectAtIndex:[arrImg count]-2];
NSString *strImg2 = [arrImg lastObject];
NSLog(@"img2-----------------%@",strImg2);
NSString *pImg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",strImg1, strImg2];
NSLog(@"img-----------------%@",pImg);
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.funnyghg.co/overheadPost.php?userId=%@&type=Photo&text=Demo test&image=%@&location=Chandigarh&Upload=Upload", uid, pImg];
NSLog(@"url :%@", urlString);
// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"1.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnString------------%@",returnString);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[appDelegate showAllNavItems];
[appDelegate navFrame];

if([returnString isEqualToString:@"true"])
{

    if([profile isEqualToString:@"friend"])
    {
        [self callServerFriend];
    }
    if([profile isEqualToString:@"public"])
    {
        [self callServerPublic];
    }
}
}
```

Please guide for the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my answer [How to upload image to server using json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965682/how-to-upload-image-to-server-using-json/15965845#15965845)

Answer (score 0):

It is because in you code there is an space in urlString between Demo and test. Please remove it as.

**Before :**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.funnyghg.co/overheadPost.php?userId=%@&type=Photo&text=Demo test&image=%@&location=Chandigarh&Upload=Upload", uid, pImg];
```

NSLog(@"url :%@", urlString);

**After :**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.funnyghg.co/overheadPost.php?userId=%@&type=Photo&text=Demotest&image=%@&location=Chandigarh&Upload=Upload", uid, pImg];
```

NSLog(@"url :%@", urlString);

I hope it will work now.

Comment: Hey thanks, it was the reason but in my code it was still not working and in your code it is giving message true in console but on server image is not getting post only text get posted..